# Looking for a tuple substitution algorithm

Tags: c++, python

I was asked this question during an interview. I knew it's a combinatorial problem but I have no idea how to solve this recursively. I am mostly looking for an approach to solving these kind of problems.

> Given a Tuple for eg. `(a, b, c)`
>
> Output :
>
> ```
> (*, *, *), (*, *, c), (*, b, *), (*, b, c), (a, *, *), (a, *, c), (a, b, *), (a, b, c)
> ```

Comment: is the order of any significance?

Comment: If you replace the asterisks with zeroes and the letters with ones, this becomes a progression of binary numbers. That may give you some idea of how to implement it.

Comment: Did the problem statement say you need to solve this recursively?  The most obvious solution would be easily coded in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a trivial one-liner using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
list(itertools.product(*(('*', x) for x in seq)))
```

This gives the same order as requested:

```
>>> list(itertools.product(*(('*', x) for x in "abc")))
[('*', '*', '*'), ('*', '*', 'c'), ('*', 'b', '*'), ('*', 'b', 'c'), ('a', '*', '*'), ('a', '*', 'c'), ('a', 'b', '*'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to implement this particular problem: for an n-ary tuple, just loop from 0 to 2^n - 1, and for each integer in between, if the k-th binary digit is 1, then the k-th position in the tuple is the original element in the tuple; if that digit is 0, then the k-th position is *.

Of course, this method will overflow easily, and is not recursive; however, it can be trivially rewritten into a recursive program (just recursively explore every binary digit).

Comment: you would need a very large number of elements to overflow this method wouldnt you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order is irrelevant, here you go. I used an internal string to make it easier to implement.The code also works for any n-tuple array for `n` that is a positive integer.

Some explanation about this implementation: set base case as 1-tuple (in my implementation, string of length one). In this case, return `*` and the content of the argument. Otherwise, advance one element in the recursion by replace current element by `*` or the content of current element.

It's easier to understand if you can draw a decision tree follow the above-mentioned algorithm.

```
def _combination(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return ['*', s]
    else:
        rest = _combination(s[1:])
        output = []
        for r in rest:
            output.append('*' + r)
            output.append(s[0] + r)
        return output

def combination(t):
    s = ''.join(c for c in t)
    result = _combination(s)
    output = []
    for r in result:
        output.append(format_tuple(r))
    print ', '.join(output)

def format_tuple(s):
    return '(' + ', '.join(s) + ')'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    combination(t)
```

Output of the program:

```
(*, *, *), (a, *, *), (*, b, *), (a, b, *), (*, *, c), (a, *, c), (*, b, c), (a, b, c)
```

Updated according to Kevin's comment.

Comment: I think if you change your base case to `['*', s]`, and reverse the two `output.append` lines in `_combinations`, your output will be ordered the same as the OP's.

Comment: @Kevin not exactly. It would be `(a, b, *), (*, b, *), (a, *, *), (*, *, *), (a, b, c), (*, b, c), (a, *, c), (*, *, c)`. IMO order is not that essential in this problem. However, if order does matter, just sort it according to whatever criteria matters after the combinations are generated.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to clwen's answer, but using generator functions, which are well suited for combinatorial problems:

```
def combinations(seq):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        yield ('*',)
        yield (seq[0],)
    else:
        for first in combinations([seq[0]]):
            for rest in combinations(seq[1:]):
                yield first + rest

print list(combinations("abc"))
```

outputs:

```
[('*', '*', '*'), ('*', '*', 'c'), ('*', 'b', '*'), ('*', 'b', 'c'), 
('a', '*', '*'), ('a', '*', 'c'), ('a', 'b', '*'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 1):

per the solutions involving binary counting (much better than the combo ones imho)

```
t_str = raw_input("Enter Tuple Values Separated By Spaces:")
t = t_str.split()
n = len(t)
bin_template = "{0:0"+str(n)+"b}"
for i in range(2**n):
    bval = bin_template.format(i)
    solution= "("+",".join(["*" if bval[i] == "0" else t[i] for i in range(n)])+")"
    print solution
```

nice and short and fast ... and it should handle tuples of anysize up to 32 (or however big ints are... and maybe even bigger since python uses arbitrarily large integers)

Comment: can you pls explain how bin_template is generating binary numbers.

Comment: its just setting a new style format string that tells it to be binary and 0 (left) padded to however many elements are in the list.."{0:03b}" in the case of the tuple from the example that is 000 = 0,001 =1,010 = 2 ,etc. but I think ecatmur's answer is better

Answer (score 0):

Since this was an interview question, the interviewer may be looking for understanding of recursion principles, since that is generally the starting point to these kind of combinatorial questions.

How about this code, to show you understand that:

```
def generate(x, state, level):
    if level == len(x):
        print state
    else:
        state[level] = '*'
        generate(x, state, level+1)
        state[level] = x[level]
        generate(x, state, level+1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [ 'a','b','c']
    generate(x,['*','*','*'], 0)
```